# Fluent NHibernate HasManyToMany and NotFound

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following FNH mapping fragment:

```
HasManyToMany((c) => c.Plaintiffs)
    .LazyLoad()
    .WithTableName("invoicePlantiff")
    .WithChildKeyColumn("PersonReferenceID")
    .WithParentKeyColumn("invoiceID")
    .FetchType.Join();
```

Which produces the following HBM:

```
<bag name="Plaintiffs" access="iServe.Design.CslaNHibernate.CslaChildPropertyAccessor, iServe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" lazy="true" table="invoicePlantiff">
  <key column="invoiceID" />
  <many-to-many column="PersonReferenceID" class="iServe.PersonReference, iServe, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" fetch="join" />
</bag>
```

The problem is that I am dealing with legacy data that is, let us just say 'less than ideal', and some records have invalid ids so I need to put the `not-found="ignore"` attribute on the many-to-many tag inside the bag.  I do not see ANY way to accomplish this with FNH.

There is the `.NotFound.Ignore()` on the `References()` call, but not on the `HasManyToMany` Call.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?  Even if it is a hack to 'inject' the attribute after it is rendered / before configuring NH is fine, i just need it to work.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** gcores answer will not work, it adds it to the wrong tag, see my comment on his answer for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just committed a change that adds `NotFound` to the `HasMany` and `HasManyToMany` calls. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but isn't there a SetAttribute?

```
HasManyToMany((c) => c.Plaintiffs)
.LazyLoad()
.WithTableName("invoicePlantiff")
.WithChildKeyColumn("PersonReferenceID")
.WithParentKeyColumn("invoiceID")
.FetchType.Join()
.SetAttributte("not-found", "ignore");
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry about that, I knew there was a SetAttribute but I wasn't sure it did what you wanted.

Another option would be to mix Fluent NH and XML mappings, the Fluent NH wiki [explains how to do this](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/FluentConfiguration) or could see this [answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391101/can-you-mix-fluent-nhibernate-and-traditional-hbm-xml).

Comment: Actually gcores that does nto work because it added the attribute to the `bag` and that is invalid.  It needs to go on the `many-to-many` inside the bag.